# selecting one item from rows based on date

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have two tables sharing a common key 'itemID', the first table holds the latest price for each itemID, the second table holds the date and value of any change to the itemID price as shown. The tLatestItemPrice table is automatically updated whenever a new entry is put into tPriceHistory table

```
tLatestItemPrice TABLE
itemID,   latestPrice
---------------------
item1     400
item2     75
item3     621


tPriceHistory TABLE
itemID,   PriceChangeDate,  NewPrice
------------------------------------
item1     Jan 8th 2012      400
item1     Jan 7th 2012      300
item1     Jan 6th 2012      280
item1     Jan 3rd 2012      270
item2     Jan 8th 2012      75
item2     Jan 5th 2012      72
item2     Jan 1st 2012      60
item3     Jan 7th 2012      621
item3     Jan 6th 2012      601
item3     Jan 2nd 2012      598
```

I want to have a query that returns me the price difference between the latest price in tLatestItemPrice table and the price of the item at a specific date. ie if I ask for the change of price between the latest and the 4th of January I want a query to return the following dataset

```
itemID    Price change from 4th Jan
--------------------------
item1     130  (i.e. 400-270)
item2      15
item3      23
```

Running mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.29, for Linux (x86_64)

Comment: are your dates really formatted like that? not `2012-01-08`?

Comment: can u give exemple from fiddle ?

Comment: Sorry, I typed the dates in for clarity, they are stored as a native DATETIME type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what it become when you have date stored as string in the table

```
SELECT  a.ITEMID, 
        d.NewPrice - a.NEWPRICE `Price change from 4th Jan`
FROM    tPriceHistory a
        INNER JOIN
        (
          SELECT itemID, 
                 DATE_FORMAT(MAX(STR_TO_DATE(PriceChangeDate, '%b %D %Y')),'%b %D %Y') maxDate
          FROM   tPriceHistory
          WHERE  STR_TO_DATE(PriceChangeDate, '%b %D %Y') <= '2012-01-04'
          GROUP BY itemID
        ) AsOfDatePrice ON a.itemID = AsOfDatePrice.ItemID AND
                           a.PriceChangeDate = AsOfDatePrice.MaxDate
        INNER JOIN 
        (
          SELECT itemID, 
                 DATE_FORMAT(MAX(STR_TO_DATE(PriceChangeDate, '%b %D %Y')),'%b %D %Y') maxDate
          FROM   tPriceHistory
          GROUP BY itemID 
        ) LatestDate ON a.itemID = LatestDate.itemid
        INNER JOIN tPriceHistory d
            ON LatestDate.itemid = d.itemID AND
               LatestDate.maxDate = d.PriceChangeDate
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo Link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/643d4/13)

Answer (score 1):

I would strongly suggest formatting your dates using a standard format that is sortable by a database (as pointed out by @JW).

Then you can do two sub-selects to get the two different prices at the given dates and in the parent query you can then perform a subtraction on their prices.

Something like this (but this is a messy quick idea!):

```
select itemID, TO_P.NewPrice as currentPrice, (FROM_P.NewPrice - TO_P.NewPrice) as priceChange
from tPriceHistory as P 
left join (select itemID, PriceChangeDate, NewPrice from PRICES where PriceChangeDate = 'from_date') as FROM_P on FROM_P.itemID = P.itemID
left join (select itemID, PriceChangeDate, NewPrice from PRICES where PriceChangeDate = 'to_date') as TO_P on TO_P.itemID = P.itemID
```

Obviously, since your dates aren't formatted in a machine friendly manner, this will only give you prices for explicit dates, you need to modify this to work with your data **and** perhaps even change your data to following a more standard date format.

Comment: This solution seems to give errors, I have created a fiddle [link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/31430) with the data I'm testing with. I Modified the query to use tPriceHistory instead of PRICES. Please bear with me, as this is my first time postinghere and using fiddle, so lots to learn

Comment: Sorry, I did mention is was messy meaning that I could only provide the idea at the time from my experience, not necessarily the full working SQL.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
  select t1.itemID,   (max(NewPrice)-min(NewPrice)) As PRICE  
  from  tPriceHistory t1

  group by t1.itemID
  order by t1.itemID
```

[**HERE DEMO SQLFIDDLE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/643d4/18)

Comment: it works on this example, but starting price is not always the minimum, and the last isn't always the maximum

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to solve this way:

```
select
  tLatestItemPrice.itemID,
  latestPrice-Substring_Index(prices, ',', -1)
from tLatestItemPrice inner join (
  select
    tPriceHistory.itemID,
    GROUP_CONCAT(NewPrice order by
       str_to_date(PriceChangeDate, '%b %D %Y')) as prices
  from tPriceHistory
  where str_to_date(PriceChangeDate, '%b %D %Y')<'2012-01-04'
  group by itemID ) mx
  on tLatestItemPrice.itemID=mx.itemID
```

(this is not always optimal, since string `price` could become longer than `group_concat_max_len` and could also be slow, but I think the idea is nice).

See [this fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/88232/1/0).